# Is there another name for power mean, where p=1/2

Tags: average

What would you call this type of average?

$\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt x_i \right) ^ 2$

Comment: I'd probably call it square-mean-root, but I don't know what the correct term would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it isn't used nearly as often as the arithmetic mean, geometric mean, or RMS, this mean doesn't have a common name other than just "the [generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) with $p=1/2$".

Answer (score 1):

This is moderately special,
but I don't think it is special enough
to have its own name.

I would call it "1/2-power mean",
with a possible explanation that the
"$r$-power mean" of 
$(a_i)_{i=1}^n$
is $ (\frac1{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{r})^{1/r}
$".